# Getting the overlap of NDEigenfunctions of different problems

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I am solving a number of Schrödinger eigenvalue problems for an array of different potentials, and I would like to calculate, in a quick, efficient and natural way, the overlap between the different eigenfunctions.

As a representative example, consider the ground-state eigenfunctions produced by a dipole and a quadrupole potential on the unit disk, as obtained with [`NDEigensystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html), i.e.

```
{{e1}, {f}} = NDEigensystem[
  {
   -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 15 x u[x, y],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]
   },
  u, {x, y} ∈ Disk[], 1
  ]
```

and

```
{{e2}, {g}} = NDEigensystem[
  {
   -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 15 (x^2 - y^2) u[x, y],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]
   },
  u, {x, y} ∈ Disk[], 1
  ]
```

I would like to calculate the integral $\int_D f(\mathbf r)^* g(\mathbf r) \mathrm d \mathbf r$. The naive way to do this would be to just put them into a `NIntegrate` construct and and let Mathematica do its thing,

```
NIntegrate[Conjugate[f[x, y]] g[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[]]
```

but this produces the error

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small

and generally it feels like there should be a better way to deal with this object that makes better use of the internal [`InterpolatingStructure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingStructure.html) mesh held by $f$ and $g$. I will be doing a lot of these as an internal part of an algorithm, so I would like to streamline this as much as possible. What are the best ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you can do is to use the same mesh for all computations:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Disk[]];
{{e1}, {f}} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 15 x u[x, y], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 1];
{{e2}, {g}} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 15 (x^2 - y^2) u[x, y],
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 1];
NIntegrate[Conjugate[f[x, y]] g[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
0.8704637241510582`
```

You should note though the giving a mesh directly to `NIntegrate` will disable adaptive refinement in `NIntegrate`. If the input are interpolating functions that should not be too much of a problem; in fact, when the mesh in the interpolation function and the one generated and refined in `NIntegrate` do not line up at the boundary that can result in problems. But your original mesh should be able to 'capture' the places in your domain where you expect action.

Comment: But would adaptive refinement in NIntegrate actually help if you have interpolating functions? Wouldn't that just try to make up more information than is actually there?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, I added a note to address your comment. See if that helps.